# How to fix : error: not an enclosing class: Context

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have the error noted in the title: `error: not an enclosing class: Context`

I already tried in some other forums to solve this problem but they couldn't help, I checked youtube and other questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer to this problem.

My code looks like this:

```
public class TermineFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button button;
    Context c;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context c) {
        super.onAttach(c);
        Context context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_3, container, false);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(Context.this, AnmeldungButton.class));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
error: not an enclosing class: Context
```

Which comes from the line:
`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(Context.this,AnmeldungButton.class));`

I want that my button in the Fragment AnmeldungButton.java is I mean in the Activity but I hope you understand me ...

Comment: `Context.this` is telling Java that you expect to be contained inside a class called `Context` and want to point to the containing instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getContext() for start activity in fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AnmeldungButton.class);                   
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you Bro , you helped me vermy much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AnmeldungButton.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }you a
   });
```

Here is the problem you are using are passing parameter in the wrong way.

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ashim ... I already tried everything out . I really appreciate it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TermineFragment extends Fragment {

Context c;
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context c) {
        super.onAttach(c);
        this.c = c; //this is one of the best way to get context of the activity to which the particular activity is associated with
    }
   @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_3, container, false);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(c,AnmeldungButton.class);//Pass the context like this.
           startActivity(intent);
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```